# Referencing func that is within another func (swift)

Tags: swift, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer, func

I've got a UIPanGestureRecognizer setup that has a couple of functions inside of it. I want to be able to reference these functions within a button.

The UIPanGestureRecognizer

```
  @IBAction func panCard(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let card = sender.view!
    let point = sender.translation(in: view)

    card.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x + point.x, y: view.center.y + point.y)

    func swipeLeft() {
        //move off to the left
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            card.center = CGPoint(x: card.center.x - 200, y: card.center.y + 75)
            card.alpha = 0
        })
    }

    func swipeRight() {
        //move off to the right
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            card.center = CGPoint(x: card.center.x + 200, y: card.center.y + 75)
            card.alpha = 0
        })
    }

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {

        if card.center.x < 75 {
            swipeLeft()
            return
        } else if card.center.x > (view.frame.width - 75) {
            swipeRight()
            return
        }

        resetCard()

    }

}
```

And the Button

```
@IBAction func LikeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

}
```

How can I reference either of the functions swipeLeft and swipeRight inside the button?

Answer (score 4):

The functions are not accessible out of their scope, which is inside your `panCard` function. Your only option is to move them outside of the scope:

```
@IBAction func panCard(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let card = sender.view!
    let point = sender.translation(in: view)

    card.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x + point.x, y: view.center.y + point.y)

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {

        if card.center.x < 75 {
            swipeLeft()
            return
        } else if card.center.x > (view.frame.width - 75) {
            swipeRight()
            return
        }

    resetCard()

    }
}

func swipeRight() {
    //move off to the right
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        card.center = CGPoint(x: card.center.x + 200, y: card.center.y + 75)
        card.alpha = 0
    })
}

func swipeLeft() {
    //move off to the left
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        card.center = CGPoint(x: card.center.x - 200, y: card.center.y + 75)
        card.alpha = 0
    })
}

@IBAction func LikeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
// swipeLeft()
// swipeRight()
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I've moved them outside of the scope along with let card = sender.view! but then getting error use of unresolved identifier 'sender' on that let.

Comment: Add a parameter to the functions:

`func swipeRight(view: NSView)`, pass `sender` as parameter and use `view` instead of `card`.

Comment: but if use NSView I get 'Use of undeclared type NSView'. I'm really new to swift so finding it a bit confusing!

Comment: `import Cocoa`.